# How much space can I dedicate with this hardware?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 165.5G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   450M  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0 299.8G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 195.3G  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 250.7G  0 part 
sdd      8:48   1   3.7G  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   1   3.7G  0 part /cdrom
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0   1.4G  1 loop /rofs
```

I will be dualbooting Ubuntu, so how much space can I dedicate for the swap and the OS?

Comment: With relatively modern hardware with lots of RAM you'll hardly need more than ~2GB swap and this is just to have some. Recommended, not mandatory, you can install without swap. For the rest use as much space as you want and the other OS permits. This is "primarily opinion-based" and likely to be closed.

Comment: You *can* dedicate as much or as little as you want.  What are you really asking?

Comment: Cause I don't know what those lines of code mean and they usually tell us to put double your RAM as swap so I thought people who knew what they were doing could help me out :D Thanks. I will put 2 gigabytes as swap and the rest as the OS.

Comment: In order to give you a proper recommendation, we need to know how you are using sda and sdb drives, what you'd like to see/do, and to see `gparted` views of those two drives. You can add the images at paste.ubuntu.com and give us the URL.

Comment: Or just `parted -l` instead of an image of gparted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in **boot menu** select any partition, for eg; `/dev/sda3` OR any other partition where you have to install **Ubuntu**.

> Note : Select a partition which has at least 100gb of space !

Select this partition and **format** it.

Now we will divide a partition into **3** sections.

### Section 1

- You can take `10gb or 5gb` for `root`.
- Type for partition - `Logical`
- Location for partition - `Beginning`
- Mount Point - `/`

### Section 2

- Use double the memory size of **RAM**(for **2gb of RAM**, **4gb space** is sufficient also not more than **8gb space** should be use) for `Swap Area`.
- Type for partition - `Logical`
- Location for partition - `Beginning`
- Use as - `Swap Area`

### Section 3

- You can take rest of the space remaining in partition.
- Type for partition - `Logical`
- Location for partition - `Beginning`
- Mount Point - `/Home`

> Note : This space is used to store documents, music, videos etc !

Comment: 10 GB is much too small for / (root) .. I would recommend at least 40 GB, and more is possible.

Comment: I didn't do section 3, is that too big of a problem? I could only open up 80 gigabytes of space, so I used 4 gigabytes for swap but I have 16 gigabytes of ram. So the rest of it went to the system which I think you refer to as root? Thanks.

Comment: well for **16 gb of RAM** you can use up to **8gb** for **swap area**, it will be sufficient. Also the rest space you have can be _root_ or _home_ . It's a matter of what type of **mount point** you have selected for rest of the space.